# Web Service Deployment to Production Server

Tags: iis, asp.net, .net, web-services

I have a old style .NET Web Service running in IIS correctly on my local machine:

http://localhost/MyService/MyService/Service1.asmx

I added a Web Reference and set it's property to dynamic so that I could simply change the URL in the Web.config file. Prior to deploying to staging server, I configured it thus:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://staging.myserver.net/MyService/MyService/Service1.asmx"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Service1Soap"
    contract="ServiceReference1.Service1Soap" name="Service1Soap" />
</client>
```

I can access it on the server like this and it works:

http://staging.myserver.net/MyService/service1.asmx

However, I need it to resolve like the following as this is how external clients are accessing it:

http://staging.myserver.net/MyService/MyService/service1.asmx

I can see nothing wrong with the IIS configuration settings on my staging server. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by adding the outer folder first, as the application in IIS. Prior to this I was pointing to the inner folder. Now I can see the nested applications in IIS and the URL I want is working.